# Does DROOLS / JBPM Workbench support pre-commit hooks?

Tags: git, drools

As the question states, does the Drools / JBPM Workbench support a pre-commit hook? I have a post-commit hook and it works just fine but my pre-commit is not getting fired.

post-commit looks like this ( works ):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "***** Calling post program - $0 for: $PWD"
```

pre-commit looks like this ( does not work ):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "***** Calling pre program - $0 for: $PWD"
```

Thanks

Comment: is your pre-commit hook chmoded executible?

Comment: Yes, I searched the web for 'Drools git hooks' and can only find references to post-commit hooks, thought I would ask here, see if anyone had ever worked with stuff like this.